# How to show up all options of html select when press down arrow in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

If you put focus on a select element, and press down button, all the options will show up in chrome, just like you click the select element, but in firefox, options will not show up when press down button, is there a way to show it up when press down/up button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering a click won't work which is the obvious answer. Maybe you could just expand the size on down arrow and set it back to 1 on the up arrow?

```
<select id="select">
<option>Value 1</option>
<option>Value 2</option>
<option>Value 3</option>
<option>Value 4</option>
</select>

jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        // down arrow (open)
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            $('#select').attr('size', $('#select option').length);
        }
        // up arrow (close)
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            $('#select').attr('size', 1);
        }   
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kxghjj3s/